# Create a table that is sized based on user input in Excel?

Tags: vba, input, excel

For the record, I'm using Excel 2010.

I'm trying to teach myself VBA for a job at work (they give the interns the VBA stuff...), and I'm getting stuck on the simplest of things.

I am trying to make a bordered table that is three columns wide. The amount of rows in the table has to be based on the amount of inputs the user has. In my code, that is the value given for `Count` by the user.

My issue is that I have no idea how to select the range I need. The only way I know how to select a range is using:

```
ActiveCell.Range("Top left cell:Bottom right cell").Select
```

If it were from `A1` to `C8`, how do I make that work? I wish it would just work like:

```
ActiveCell.Range("A1:C(count)").Select
```

This is what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Count As Long
Dim CFLArray() As Variant
Sub TableCreation1()
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Time (days)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "CFL (measured)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "De (estimated)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Range("A1:C1").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveCell.Offset(0,2).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveCell.Select
End Sub

Sub FindRange()
    Range("A2").Select
    Count = InputBox("How many pairs of data do you have? ")
End Sub
```

I taught myself VBA a day or so ago using a book my work had, but I couldn't find anything along these lines in there. My internet searches failed as well. The worst part is I know it's going to be incredibly simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is that simple! You were just off by a little bit.

Change: `ActiveCell.Range("A1:C(count)").Select`

To: `ActiveCell.Range("A1:C" & count).Select`

Though, I don't see any `count` variable in your code.

If you know that it's always the same column, you could do this:

`Range("A1:C" & ActiveSheet.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row).Select`

(`1048576` is the max row in Excel 2010. This may not be perfect for your data, but hopefully it will get you started in the right direction...)

Also, just as an added point about VBA, you don't need to use `Select` in most cases. For example, this:

```
Range("A1").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Time (days)"
```

Can be rewritten more simply as:

```
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Time (days)"
```

And if you are just using text:

```
Range("A1").value = "Time (days)"
```

---

I also want to point out that using `ActiveCell.Range("A1:C" & count).Select` is not the same as `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C" & count).Select`. Depending on what cell is currently selected, these will select different ranges. If you really mean `A1:C8`, and not `A1:C8 (relative to the current cell)`, then you'll want to use the `ActiveSheet` (or omitted) version.

Comment: `ActiveCell.EntireRow.End(xlUp).Row` ==> does it work if ActiveCell is not on the first line?

Comment: @assylias Yup. just added that to my answer (see end).

Comment: You have to scroll down inside of the code to see the count variable for some reason.

Comment: @user1506937 Ha! Silly me. I saw your `Sub` end right at the bottom of the code block, so I had assumed that was all there was.

Comment: As a follow-up question, what if I want to select two cells next two each other on the row that is Count down?

Like A(count) to B(count) ?

I tried: 

    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Count ":B" & Count).Select

But it didn't work.

Comment: @user1506937 Make sure you use the `&` on both ends of your strings, like so: `ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Count & ":B" & Count).Select`

Comment: Thank you :) That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

That would be:

```
ActiveCell.Range("A1:C" & Count).Select
```

The `&` is the string concatenation operator.

---

Side note - your first procedure (TableCreation1) could be rewritten more concisely:

```
Sub TableCreation1()

  Range("A1") = "Time (days)"
  Range("B1") = "CFL (measured)"
  Range("C1") = "De (estimated)"
  Range("A1:C1").Font.Bold = True
  Columns("A:C").EntireColumn.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate this.

I'm actually having a blast learning how to program. You guys are making it much less painful for me. :)